# Internals of ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Are there any good books or papers that explain the inner workings of rails from the top down? Not how to use it but what is actually happening for instance when you run the server or send a request to the server.

Comment: Do you have any context for this? I.E why are you looking for this information?

Comment: I want to sharpen my skills. A lot. So I want to know about how it's implemented and in general how things flow. I have been able to figure out a lot using breakpoints and RubyMine but was looking for any new links to the internals.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a good jumping off point: 
[Rails initialization process](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/source/initialization.md)

Rack abstracts most of the webserver:
[Rack documentation](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/)

And then how rails interacts with Rack to handle requests:
[Rails on Rack](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/source/rails_on_rack.md)

I demystified the inner workings of Rails for myself by reading through those (and other RoR core guides), and exploring the source.  Hopefully that helps.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the request response cycle? Checkout http://devhub.fm/http-requestresponse-basics/ to learn more. Also, you can use a tool like [burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/) to dig into this some more. Once you understand this, you can dig into Nic's suggestions and they will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Two good links:
Rebuilding Rails: http://codefol.io/posts/47-Class-Index

Railscasts episode 299 Rails initialization Walkthrough